# What is the correct Laravel-way to define a method (public function) inside a model and execute the function inside a controller?

Tags: php, laravel, oop

I have a method to calculate the price of a specific product. I wrote some code **that is working**, but I have a feeling that it's not "the correct way" of doing it. Am I doing this wrong or is there a better way? This is what I got:

The ProductsController:

```
$amount = 10;
$product = Product::where('type', $type)->firstOrFail();
dd($product->getPrice($amount, $product['id']));
```

The Product (model):

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Product extends Model
{
    public function getPrice($amount, $product_id) {

    $product = Product::where('id', $product_id)->firstOrFail();
    $product_price = $product['price'] * $amount;
    return $product_price;

    }

}
```

I will have much more complicated calculations inside the getPrice method in the future. I want to be able to get a products price on the checkout page with this method. The exact product price needs some complicated calculations and is not stored by itself inside the database.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you call your function, `getPrice` for the specific model, you already have the information about it so there is no need to retrieve it once more.

Inside your model, when defining functions, you can always assume that the product is already fetched and using `$this` inside your functions will refer to that product. There are some exceptions to this, but it's out of the scope for this question.

What you wrote can behave the same with one less query:

ProductController:

```
$amount = 10;
$product = Product::where('type', $type)->firstOrFail();
dd($product->getPrice($amount));
```

Product:

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Product extends Model
{
    public function getPrice($amount) {
      $product_price = $this->price * $amount;
      return $product_price;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

The best way is to separate the logic into services.

Create a new directory, Services, inside the app folder. In there, create a class and call it ProductService(or anything else). Put all your logic and calculations here.

```php
namespace App\Services;

class ProductService{
  public function calculatePrice(int $productId, int $amount){
    $singlePrice = Product::findOrFail($productId)->price;
    return $singlePrice*$amount;
  }

  //add more functions here
}
```

In your controllers or anywhere else you need them, unject them in the controller:

```php
class BlahBlahController{
  .
  .
  .
  private $productService;

  public function __construct(ProductService $productService){
    $this->productService = $productService;
  }
  .
  .
  .
}
```

now use the service anywhere in your controllers.

Comment: Though this answer is nice, it's not an answer to OP's question. Now he needs to create a whole class and learn dependency injection just to execute a simple `get` function.

Comment: @Loek allow me to respectfully disagree. OP asked for a better way, and this is a better way. Isn't it good that OP got introduced to the very basic of a good programming pattern?

Comment: @Loek the OP is asking about a correct way or a better way. of course, we could do it in a lot of spaghettie-ish ways, but I'm sensing the OP would not want them.

Comment: Fair enough. This is one of those opinionated cases and there's a reason we flag them at SO. Personally, I find this answer a bloated and unnecessarilly complex solution. But in a 100,000 line codebase, this solution is a dream.

Comment: Thank you guys for showing me this option. It helps me understand Laravel better!

Answer (score 0):

A more 'Laravel' way might be to define an [accessor](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor) for the price.

If you have a `price` column in your table, just create a `public function getPriceAttribute($value) {...}` method in your model then you can access the `price` attribute 'directly' and the magic will happen without you having to call a separate method.